# Woocommerce Webshop on bitnami stack (ec2): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, openssl, bitnami

I simply can't find a solution to this. I migrated a Wordpress site with a woocommerce shop and payment gateway "Payunity" to a new EC2 machine with a bitnami wordpress stack.
I generated a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate and the entire site works as expected.

Only problem I have is that for some reason on the woocommerce checkout page I suddenly get this error message:

[image]

> SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate
>   verify failed

I googled extensively and tried figuring this out but no chance.

Any idea what I have to set on the server to have this go away? I tried modifying the php.ini with the capath and cafile like some threads pointed out but no luck.

Any ideas?

***Update: I now moved to Cloudflare as DNS Manager and have the "Full (strict) setting so that the Cloudflare SSL is the one in use. However still the same error, so I figure this has nothing todo with the original Let's Encrypt or now Cloudflare SSL Certificate.***

Comment: Hallo matt. What was shown at this position when everything worked? What is the PHP and CURL version you are using?

Comment: Hey @Johannes … bitnami wordpress stack with PHP Version 7.2.13 and curl 7.45.0 

What you mean what was shown when everything worked? No error message, that's it. Every checkout worked smoothly but now the payment gateway which btw is Payunity (https://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/wordpress-woocommerce-payunity-zahlungs-plugin.html) … for credticard and paypal payments. Always worked fine so far. Never had a problem.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your site's SSL. The error is almost for sure about your site's PHP code connecting to a SSL-secured resource, and it is not able to verify that certificate. Can you provide log files (PHP error log, Wordpress/Woocommerce/Payunity logging? See also <https://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/chf/software/manual/index/en/wordpress-woocommerce-payunity-zahlungs-plugin.html/#chapter_10>)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this error message is caused by CURL. According to the CURL FAQ (https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/FAQ) section 4.12 (where exactly this error message is mentioned), *"it means that curl couldn't verify that the server's certificate was good. Curl verifies the certificate using the CA cert bundle that comes with the curl installation."* (vsince CURL 7.10).

As your CURL version is quite old ([released](https://github.com/curl/curl/releases?after=curl-7_47_0) on Oct 7, 2015), I would assume that one of the CA/root certificates it is using is too old. I would recommend updating CURL separately (e.g. using this guide: http://pavelpolyakov.com/2014/11/17/updating-php-curl-on-ubuntu/, depending on your OS).
Furthermore, you can check the `openssl.cafile` option in `php.ini` that should point to an absolute path containing a more or less recent CA bundle (e.g. "C:\xampp7.3\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt" for my XAMPP installation). You can try to extract the bundle from the XAMPP `.zip` (https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and replace the path in your `php.ini` and then restart the server.

In addition, you can check your `php.ini` if `extension=php_openssl.*` (extension e.g. `dll` for Windows) is uncommented, i.e. activated.

Maybe (and this is why I asked what should be shown normally at this place) a script inside the `Payunity` plugin is trying to fetch something from an URL with a broken certificate or something similar.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Sebastian B., you can check the `error.log` (in case of Apache) for failed `file_get_contents()` (or similar) calls because the actual URL of the "file" the site PHP tried to fetch is mentioned there.

**EDIT:** CURL Perl script to create a fresh `ca-bundle.crt` file based on Mozilla's chain: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/mk-ca-bundle.pl You can try this (or extract one from a fresh CURL installation) and set this as a path in `php.ini`. Or you can use this from the Nextcloud project (https://github.com/nextcloud/server/blob/master/resources/config/ca-bundle.crt) or another one (just for testing purposes, of course).

Comment: @matt Have you had the chance to try this out? Is it leading in the right direction?

Comment: sorry I was not able to check this so far but will be able by tomorrow. thanks however for your feedback so far.

Comment: Hey @johannes. I finally got the chance to test your suggestion. I now upgraded to curl 7.70 which is my version now. This did not resolve the issue. I'll now check the further details of your post.

Comment: Please check using `phpinfo()` if PHP actually uses the new curl version. I think what will resolve the issue is replacing the certificate.

Comment: yes it is replaced. info.php shows the latest curl version of 7.70 … https://imgur.com/eiCaMHK I now created a ca-bundle.crt file on the server and pasted the contents of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nextcloud/server/master/resources/config/ca-bundle.crt into it. I then made sure the php.ini file is having this as a path here: https://imgur.com/VUw8rbf … I restarted apache and php-fpm and tried again. No luck. Same error message.

Comment: This is the apache error_log: https://imgur.com/gXAgEes

Comment: What happens if you replace the WooCommerce function by the non-deprecated one?

Comment: I think the problem is simply a deprecated plugin version of a paid plugin, I will update the plugin with the help of the plugin support and it shuold work.

Comment: Great. I would be interested what the solution actually was, feel free to share it with us!

Comment: Yes the solution was that the payment woocommerce plugin simply had a certificate problem with this openssl thing. They have a newer version of the plugin that solves for this issue. I don't know the details, but I guess it goes into your direction but essentially the plugin takes care of it and not the php.ini updates.